# I need help with designing a specific circuit

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

Design an arithmetic unit. Let A and B be two 4-bit 2’s complement numbers. Design a circuit to compute:

Z = A + B         if k1k0=00

A + B + 1  if k1k0=01

A                if k1k0=10

A - B        if k1k0=11

Add logic to your above design that computes V, which is 1 when the output is a valid number and 0 when it is invalid. Assume signed numbers are always used.

I know the A+B and A-B can be done with a design like this
[image]

And I assume we'll need a MUX with k(1,0) being the select signal. But I'm stuck as to how to do the valid/invalid part.

Comment: It is very, very easy to look up the logic applied to get the V (overflow) bit. All you have to do is copy the work of others. Have you attempted to do that already?

Comment: @jonk can you explain how overflow and validity are the same? I originally thought those were the same but after I did some research on that (there were no concrete yes or no's) I came to the conclusion that they weren't the same.

Comment: I took them to mean the same because of the wording in your problem. Facts: (1) The problem involves "signed numbers." (2) The problem wants "1 when the output is a valid number and 0 when it is invalid." An output is always valid if there is no overflow, unless there is a definition in the problem creating a different meaning for "valid." Since there is not a different definition, I'm left to assume by the law of parsimony to the conclusion that it's about signed overflow. Do you have *any* facts at hand that would disagree?

Comment: The actual sense of the bit (whether "1" in this case or that case) isn't really important. That's just a detail. So it's not important to me if V=1 means "OK" or means "ERROR." That can be left as a final detail to work out. So the problem may be asking for the exact opposite of the usual overflow bit meaning. But who cares? That's just a "fix up" at the end. If you look at the usual overflow logic, the worst that can happen to you is that the sense is the opposite of the usual case. Oh, well. Trivial to solve.

Comment: you have a typo in your question ... `Let and B ...`

Comment: i think that the valid/invalid term has something to do with logic race condition

Comment: @jonk thank you for explaining all that out! I didn't understand that the output is valid if there is no overflow bit. That helps a lot

Comment: Yes. You might add two negative numbers together whose sum is larger than is possible in the format. You need to signal that as a problem. The same for adding two positive numbers where their sum is also larger than possible in the format. Without the V bit, one might assume that adding two positive numbers to get a negative number is a valid result. Not so good.